# Как организовать обмен данными между серверами?

Tags: node.js, сокет, http, request

Есть центральный сервер, который будет принимать от пользователей запросы и обмениваться с серверами, в зависимости от нужды обращения к тому или иному серверу.

Был бы хорошо узнать, что лучше использовать и как. То есть `sockets` или `http` запросы, `TCP` итд итп. Ссылки на ресурсы, где можно почитать о той или иной реализации. НУ и конечно же бесценный опыт.

На серверах будет крутиться node, из бд на центральном `mysql`, а на второстепенных `mongodb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте ту технологию, **которую вы хорошо знаете**, и конечно она должна быть достаточно популярной чтобы можно было легко найти разработчика.

Опишу достаточно типичную ситуацию:

обычно серверная система состоит из достаточно большого количества связанных между собой компонентов, это:

- *базы данных,*
- *очереди,*
- *веб-серверы,*
- *прокси-серверы,*
- *балансировщики,*
- *системы мониторинга,*
- *резервирования*

Всё это необходимо развернуть, настроить, наполнить тестовыми данными. А потом периодически обновлять и пересобирать, так как многие компоненты находятся в активной разработке. Кстати, из сложности и гетерогенности серверной системы следует необходимость как-то этой сложностью управлять. Это всевозможные системы развертывания, управления, конфигурирования, мониторинга, диагностики, сбора, анализа и хранения логов. Подчас на разработку этих инфраструктурных компонентов приходится тратить львиную долю сил и времени.

Не забудьте про масштабируемость. Когда происходит серьёзный наплыв пользователей. Нагрузка на серверную систему возрастает. Одна из подсистем (обычно это база данных) немного деградирует из-за увеличившейся нагрузки, начинает медленнее отвечать или вообще перестаёт укладываться в приемлемое время ответа. Вследствие этого возрастает общее время обработки одного запроса на сервере бизнес-логики, что, в свою очередь, приводит к увеличению числа одновременно работающих процессов-воркеров. На сервере заканчивается свободная память, операционная система, пытаясь обслужить возросшее количество процессов, теперь в основном занимается переключением контекстов и перетасовкой страниц в памяти. Это ещё больше ухудшает положение. Тут в дело включается балансировщик, выкидывая из нагрузки затупивший сервер и тем самым увеличивая нагрузку на оставшиеся в строю серверы. Поздравляем, наш сайт прилёг, и поднять его без снятия нагрузки будет очень проблематично.

Понятное дело, подобные ситуации возникают обычно только в самом начале развития нового сервиса. В дальнейшем либо разработчики исправляют недостаток системы, либо сервис постепенно загибается.

Чтобы успешно переживать такие эксцессы, серверное ПО должно быть достаточно «эластичным» и масштабируемым. Тогда рост нагрузки приведёт не к отказу сервиса целиком, а, например, лишь к незначительной деградации по скорости обработки запросов. В таком случае временное повышение нагрузки можно просто переждать, а если нагрузка возросла навсегда (то есть сервис стал популярнее), достаточно компенсировать её, доставив необходимое количество серверов. Иногда для этого приходится серьёзно перерабатывать архитектуру всего приложения, целенаправленно выискивая и устраняя самые узкие места системы.